# Capture desktop with Aforge

Tags: c#, wpf, video, desktop, aforge

I have seen various tutorial like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473898/writing-on-a-bitmap-not-working-for-writing-a-frame-with-a-forge) on how to make a video from webcam, show and record it.
What I would like now is to be able to do the same with the desktop so that I can cross-reference the computer activity with the external world.
So  what I would like is to be able to record a video of what happens on the computer possibly usig AForge.
I found no reference about that, is it therefore impossible to do with Aforge?

--ADD--

I have implemented the proposed solution as below:
[image]

Thanks

but when I look at the png is all black.
The saving procedure is correct for when I save the webcam frame it is ok. Could you please tell me what is wrong in my adaptation from your code?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "Zoom-like" application by _cross-reference_?

Comment: No much more simply I want to see what the user does at a certain time and what happens in the real world

Comment: So, you mean that real-time desktop sharing? If so, it may not have to do with Aforge.NET. Because you need to capture the screen and share that via internet, right?

Comment: No I simply need to record on file. I thought about Aforge for I am recording webcam through it. So I thought it was the simpliest way.

Comment: You can use `VideoFileWriter` class in namespace `Aforge.Video.FFMPEG`.

Comment: Yes I use that but only for webcams not for desktop

Comment: FFMpeg wiki/manual has a "how to capture the desktop" section. I'd just ask ffmpeg to capture your desktop as one stream and your cam as another, muxed into the same file

Comment: You might also want to put the desktop image on top of the other so as to have what you call cross-reference between what the user does on the computer and the real world from the webcam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be a professionally solution and not realtime but it does the work for simple scenarios like yours. It is a console application built with Net Framework 4.7.2. And I rebuilt the assembly `Aforge.Video.FFMPEG` by using its source code so that it can be used with Net Framework 4.0+.

```
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
    {
        static VideoFileWriter VideoFileWriter;
        static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VideoFileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();

            Size screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
            VideoFileWriter.Open("test.mp4", screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height, 30, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 19200000);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            stopwatch.Start();
            while (stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)) // Record for ten seconds.
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenSize, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                VideoFileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bitmap, stopwatch.Elapsed);
                Thread.Sleep(29);
            }
            VideoFileWriter.Close();
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please exaplain me the purpose of the Thread.Sleep(29); command? If it is to make VideoFileWriter wouldn't it be better to put a lower frame rate?

Comment: I have implemented your solution but even if looks good it produces an all black image. Could you please tell me where I go wrong? Thanks

Comment: Its purpose is to wait for sometime until the next frame, in this case, it is 30ms. Since Thread.Sleep doesn't gurantee that it will sleep 30ms exactly, in practice, you should choose lower than 30ms. By the way I didn't choose a correct value. Yeah, it would be better to capture the desktop in high fps. You can tweak it how you want. But the runtime of capturing must take 30ms approximately or lower than that. Graphics.CopyFromScreen is not that bad but not enough fast. You can search for other options to capture the desktop on SO.

Comment: It doesn't produces any black image on my laptop with dual graphics card. It may be caused by how your desktop is rendered (CPU or GPU).